# php-mysql: Array from query is duplicated

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am extracting data related to an "opening hours" table to fill an array that will further be used by a function. I use the INNER join method to get only the opening hours of one specific shop from which the id is set in a profil table.

this is the code:

```
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='dbName.';charset=utf8','root', '');

$answ=$bdd->query('SELECT  OpeningHours.day, OpeningHours.open, OpeningHours.closed
                        FROM Profil 
                        INNER JOIN OpeningHours 
                        ON OpeningHours.ID= Profil.ID
                        WHERE Profil.ID= 2'); 


while ($array = $answ->fetch()) {

    $opening_hours[]=$array['day'];
}

print_r(array_values($opening_hours));
```

And the result I get:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 4 [5] => 5 [6] => 6 )
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 4 [5] => 5 [6] => 6 )
```

Which is the array I expect but in a duplicate.

If I use the MySQL selection in phpMyAdmin I get the table like I expect it to be:

```
+-----+-------+--------+
| day | open  | closed | 
+-----+-------+--------+
|   0 | 09:00 | 17:30  |
|   1 | 09:00 | 17:30  | 
|   2 | 09:00 | 17:30  | 
|   3 | 09:30 | 19:00  | 
|   4 | 09:30 | 19:00  |
|   5 | 09:30 | 16:00  |
|   6 | 09:30 | 16:00  | 
+-----+-------+--------+
```

I really can't get why the array comes 2 times!

Comment: you're probably running this code twice. You've got two entirely separate `print_r` outputs in there, which means your code is running twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc B, the code was indeed running twice. I was so concentrated on testing stuff that I dident see it!